# Как правильно масштабировать блок через css?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Такая ситуация: есть 2 блока - белый и красный. Красный нельзя редактировать, изменять длину, ширину, только пропорции. Такой вопрос: что нужно сделать, чтобы красный блок влез в белый.

CSS красного блока:

```
.red_container {
    min-width: 850px;
    max-width: 850px;
    height: 500px;
    background-color: red;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 50px 70px;
}
```

P.S. Можно сделать через transform scale, но мне кажется что есть более простой выход

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Через transform и есть более простой способ, наверно...

Comment: ну, покажите как Вы сделали, через scale

Comment: @Дмытрык: учитывая то, что в метках вопроса присутствует JS, то можно хоть слона в спичечный коробок утрамбовать. Тут [XY problem](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_XY), ибо следующим вопросом будет "как теперь заставить слона прыгать на батуте, если коробок не позволяет" ;-)